# # truncating environment variables in Linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, environment-variables

I'm using the etc/environment file to keep track of my environment variables in Linux Mint, and I've noticed that if I have an environment variable with the symbol "#" that it truncates the environment variable. For example,

TEST_VAR="My team is #1 in the world"

will come out as:

TEST_VAR="My team is "

Does anyone know how to get around this? I can't find any documentation on symbols that aren't allowed in environment variables for linux mint. Should i just avoid special characters in environment variables?

Comment: `#` is a comment symbol. Try escaping it with a backslash `\#`

Comment: I think you're right about "#" being a comment symbol. However, backslash isn't escaping it. Instead I get: TEST_VAR="My team is \". Tried a forward slash too and got the same thing.